# Dateformatter returns wrong year for 2017-12-31

Tags: ios, nsdate

Look at this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"YYYY-MM-dd";
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Log:

```
Printing description of date:
2017-12-31 11:04:07 +0000
Printing description of dateString:
2018-12-31
```

How did I get **2018**???

BTW, this code works perfectly for every other date. It only behaves weird on 2017-12-31...

UPDATE:

Trying to use system time zone, as suggested in comment:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"YYYY-MM-dd";
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Log:

```
Printing description of date:
2017-12-31 11:27:04 +0000
Printing description of dateString:
2018-12-31
```

Comment: try using systemTimeZone rather than hard coding UTC  `formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];`

Comment: @SandeepBhandari look at my update.

Comment: @Gal Try with `y` instead of `Y` as vadian said.

Comment: @dahiya_boy thank you